# MySQL - Select next row if previous row field was 1, select first row if next row does not exist?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `room_players`
(`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY  
,`player_id` int(11) NOT NULL  
,`room_id` tinyint(1) NOT NULL  
,`dealer` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO room_players (`player_id`, `room_id`, `dealer`) VALUES
(1,    1,    '0'),
(2,    1,    '0'),
(3,    1,    '0'),
(4,    1,    '1'),
(5,    1,    '0');
```

I need to get row after `WHERE dealer='1' AND room_id='1'`; in this case, it should return `player_id = 5`.

Now, when `dealer = 1` for `player_id = 5`, then it should select the first `player_id` of the current `room_id`.

I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM room_players 
WHERE room_id='1' 
AND id IN ( SELECT ID+1 
            FROM room_players 
            WHERE room_id='1' 
            AND dealer != 1
           )
```

Selecting the next row works with this query but, when we got to the last player in line, it will return nothing.

I could run 2 different queries to get it work, but I would like to use an eloquent single query.

Comment: First thing, you don't need to add IDs in the data if you already have `AUTO_INCREMENT` set on the `id` column.

Comment: @VickyDev alright, i'm not sure why it matters to you, but i edited my question.

Comment: Tables have no order defined.  So is your "get row after"  how do you define your order, by player ID?  and can there be gaps in your player_ids or in teh "id" itself?

Comment: Will it always be the row player immediatley after this condition... If if there is a 2nd, 3rd room etc. Is it guaranteed that there is only one row whith 1 and 1, or for room 2 I guess 2 and 1? What if the 'last player is you're 1 and 1 case?

What is the aim of the query? If its get the next player after the 'dealer', this is broken if the dealer is the last player in the list of players for that room.

Comment: @MarkoTõnisson Just a suggestion, many things could go wrong if the you manually provide IDs in the data and somehow the IDs are not in order or mistyped.

Comment: I think you're table is poorly designed... Ultimatley.

Comment: @xQbert order by id ASC

Comment: @Brian dealer can be 0 or 1 (false or true), if the dealer is the last player in that room it should select first row of room_id = 1.

Comment: I was thinking something like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=12eeb812451b229f356b7c59f9b49930 but it's not right...

Comment: @xQbert thanks, it is a good try, but i think its more complicated than doing separate queries.

Comment: @MarkoTõnisson  updated answer think this is close...  Just unsure what the true expected output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with slightly different approach, i got to solve it with one simple query, but did some coding with PHP also. Its not the eloquant i wanted, but it works for me.

```
        function dealer($room_id) {
        global $con;    
        $array = array();
        
        $i = 0;
        $cd = null;
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM room_players WHERE room_id='".$room_id."'");
        while($ft = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $array[] = array("user_id" => $ft['user_id']);
            
            if($ft['dealer'] == 1) {
                $cd = $i;
            }
            
            $i++;
        }
        
        if(!is_null($cd)) {
            if($array[$cd+1]) {
                $next = $array[$cd+1];
                }else{
                $next = $array[0];  
            }
            }else{
            $next = $array[array_rand($array, 1)];
        }
        
        return $next['user_id'];
    }
    
    echo "Next dealer is: ". dealer(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using window functions we can achieve this in 1 query pretty easily:

- first_value() asending id
- first_value() descending id
- lead()
- case expression to figure out when to display next dealer value.
- Just note: elegance of 1 query may make maintenance more complex.

  - it's not always better to build 1 sometimes two IS simplier.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ccaef12778408ab1a1d43fe5f1264123)
you can adjust dealer to wherever you want and it will return the next dealer player number on the dealer number line.  you didn't define expected results so I am unsure what you result is to look like.

```
SELECT * 
       , case WHEN dealer=1 and player_id = first_value(player_id) over (partition by room_id order by id desc)  
              THEN first_value(player_id) over (partition by room_id order by id)
              WHEN dealer=1 
              THEN lead(player_id)  over (partition by room_id order by id) end as NextDealer
      From room_players
```

Giving us:

```
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------------+
| id | player_id | room_id | dealer | NextDealer |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------------+
|  1 |         1 |       1 |      0 |            |
|  2 |         2 |       1 |      1 |          3 |
|  3 |         3 |       1 |      0 |            |
|  4 |         4 |       1 |      0 |            |
|  5 |         5 |       1 |      0 |            |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------------+
```

or

```
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------------+
| id | player_id | room_id | dealer | NextDealer |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------------+
|  1 |         1 |       1 |      0 |            |
|  2 |         2 |       1 |      0 |            |
|  3 |         3 |       1 |      0 |            |
|  4 |         4 |       1 |      0 |            |
|  5 |         5 |       1 |      1 |          1 |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+------------+
```

depending on who is dealer..

[DB Fiddle expanded](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af5cd3eed39a53f42dfbfed37662ac19) to show what's happening with case expression & show how to get dealer/room.  Yes I had to use a CTE because the window functions can't have the data limited; it first must have the data materialized.    But, if you create the CTE as a view and you're simply passing in the room to get the next dealer this works fine imo.

We can use:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, 
 case WHEN dealer=1 and player_id = first_value(player_id) over (partition by room_id order by id desc)  
              THEN first_value(player_id) over (partition by room_id order by id)
              WHEN dealer=1 
              THEN lead(player_id)  over (partition by room_id order by id) end  NextDealer
      From room_players)
SELECT room_id, NextDealer FROM CTE WHERE NextDealer is not null
```

to get data by room and next dealer giving us: (I added some additional test data to make sure certain edge cases were working as expected)

```
+---------+------------+
| room_id | NextDealer |
+---------+------------+
|       1 |          7 |
|       2 |         99 |
+---------+------------+
```

With Date of:

```
+----+-----------+---------+--------+
| id | player_id | room_id | dealer |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+
|  1 |         1 |       1 |      0 |
|  2 |         2 |       1 |      0 |
|  3 |         3 |       1 |      0 |
|  4 |         4 |       1 |      1 |
|  5 |         7 |       1 |      0 |
|  6 |        99 |       2 |      0 |
|  7 |        14 |       2 |      0 |
|  8 |        22 |       2 |      0 |
|  9 |        77 |       2 |      1 |
| 10 |        15 |       2 |      0 |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+
```

I get:

```
+----+-----------+---------+--------+----+----+----+------------+
| id | player_id | room_id | dealer | a  | b  | c  | NextDealer |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+----+----+----+------------+
|  1 |         1 |       1 |      0 |  7 |  1 |  2 |            |
|  2 |         2 |       1 |      0 |  7 |  1 |  3 |            |
|  3 |         3 |       1 |      0 |  7 |  1 |  4 |            |
|  4 |         4 |       1 |      1 |  7 |  1 |  7 |          7 |
|  5 |         7 |       1 |      0 |  7 |  1 |    |            |
|  6 |        99 |       2 |      0 | 15 | 99 | 14 |            |
|  7 |        14 |       2 |      0 | 15 | 99 | 22 |            |
|  8 |        22 |       2 |      0 | 15 | 99 | 77 |            |
|  9 |        77 |       2 |      1 | 15 | 99 | 15 |         15 |
| 10 |        15 |       2 |      0 | 15 | 99 |    |            |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+----+----+----+------------+
```

Comment: Almost works as expected, except when player ids does not rise incrementally. In example higher player id won't be selected, when the next player_id is lower.

Comment: hmm... in my example if I set player 99 or 77 in room 2 to be the "Dealer" 14, or 15 respectively is selected.    These are the next player based on 'id' Can you provide an example set of data where this is occurring?   [My Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c3955db601aef8577fa07fbc3d53df9)  player's ids should be irrelevant; we're basing this on the 'id' of the records which were to be incremental I thought.  if not, I'll need to assign a row number to each as well and use it instead of ID; but that has to be done 1st... so a 2nd CTE would be needed.

Comment: I updated my answer to show my data set and results when deal is 77, the next record 15 has a lower player number yet gets displayed as the "next dealer" for room 2.  I don't understand the problem well enough to address it yet.  If you just want to add a room 3 or amend existing data to show me the problem I'd be happy to address it (repost updated link!)

Comment: Thank you for your time, but at this point i went with different approach.

Comment: Welcome. You may want to update your tags to indicate php acceptable as well for future users.